# Is it neccessary to create a microservice for data that is used in several microservices in order to avoid duplication?

Tags: microservices, entities

I would like to ask if some data, as for example categories or locations, is necessary in different microservices, should I make a new microservice for them in order to use them everywhere and not create duplicate entities with duplicate data? Or what would be the best approach?